# Can the Kalman Filter process covariance be estimated from measurements?

Tags: kalman-filters

I'm looking for the simplest possible method for estimating the process noise covariance $\mathbf{Q}$ and measurement noise covariance $\mathbf{R}$ for a Kalman Filter. This is assuming a time-invariant system, that is the state transition matrix $\mathbf{A}$, control matrix  $\mathbf{B}$ and observation matrix $\mathbf{H}$ are all constant.

[This introductory text](http://www.cs.unc.edu/%7Ewelch/kalman/kalmanIntro.html) contains a short section titled *Filter Parameters and Tuning* (p. 6) which reads in part:

> In the actual implementation of the filter, the measurement noise covariance $\mathbf{R}$ is usually measured prior to operation of the filter. Measuring the measurement error covariance $\mathbf{R}$ is generally practical (possible) because we need to be able to measure the process anyway (while operating the filter) so we should generally be able to take some off-line sample measurements in order to determine the variance of the measurement noise. *(…)*
> The determination of the process noise covariance $\mathbf{Q}$ is generally more difficult as we typically do not have the ability to directly observe the process we are estimating.

In the above, how exactly would one measure *"the measurement error covariance $\mathbf{R}$"?* Is it enough to collect a set of measurements, then compute its covariance matrix?

And what would it take for us to *"have the ability to directly observe the process we are estimating"?* Should that be arranged, how then to compute $\mathbf{Q}$?